# Eclipse build-place

Tags: android, eclipse, build, apk

Where can I change the place where my applicationname.apk (Android) will be built in Eclipse? By default it is in the `/bin` directory, but how could I change this?

I need this because I want to share the `.apk` file automatically with my friends using Ubuntu One, but I don't want to synchronize the other files in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse right click on your project and choose Properties. A window will open, now choose In the left you have several options choose Java Build Path. After choose Java Build path you need to select the tab source and in the bottom choose your default output folder. By default it's bin

Comment: I found it, but by me there is displayed `TicTacToe/bin/classes`. But the .apk is not in `/bin/classes` but in `/bin`. In `/bin/classes` are only the classes and not an .apk.